# ArrayList incompatibile types

Tags: java, arraylist

in my project I have some classes like this:

```
class A
class B extends A
class C extends A
```

Now, in my Main class, I have an `ArrayList` which look like this:

`ArrayList<A> list`

now when I want to instantiate one with elements of types B or C its ok when I do it like this:

`list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(b1, b2, c1, c2));`

but when I want to add here only types of C or B class like this:

`list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(c1, c2, c3));`

IntelliJ complains about `ArrayList incompatibile types` but when I add A type like this:
`list = new ArrayList<A>(Arrays.asList(c1, c2, c3));`

everything is ok. Why is that?

Comment: can't reproduce on intelliJ.

Comment: It would help if you'd provide a [mcve] rather than just snippets. We can put one together ourselves, but it's much better if you do it *once* rather than each potential answerer doing it themselves.

Comment: Maybe the diamond operator doesn't know what type to infer in your error-case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Java7 Oracle introduce the diamond operator. This operator use reflextion to determine the type from the parameter or from the return value. Before you always have to fill in the type to a generic class.

The problem is that you have one generic class in an other and for der inner generic methode `Arrays.asList()` mixed parameter types and the return value is also not defined (parameter from outer methode is generic). So the compiler can't figure out witch class is meant.

This depents on the instant compiler from the IDE. Eclipse Neon 3 supports expressions like:

```
list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(b1, b2, c1, c2);
```

But is always a good advise to write the types for better readability and debugging reasons. Your Code can also written as:

```
ArrayList<A> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.<A>asList(b1,b2,c1,c2));
```

For more infos visit the oracle documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html